# Count of the Course Name

Tags: php, mysql

i am struggling with one logic in query

i have two tables called "students" and "courses" here i need the count of the students in particular course

```
 students table
 student_id | course_id 
   1           11
   2           11
   3           11
   4           12
   5           12
   6           13
   7           18

courses table
course_id | course_name
   11          test
   12          test
   13          xyz
   18          xyz
```

Here what is my requirement is i want the how students are there in same course name of the students irrespective of the course_id

```
output i need is

course_name | student_count
 test              5
 xyz               2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.`course_name`, count(s.`student_id`) AS student_count FROM course c, students s WHERE s.`course_id` = c.`course_id` GROUP BY c.`course_name`;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select c.course_name, count(s.student_id) as student_count
from courses c
left join students s on s.course_id = c.course_id
group by c.course_name
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592e4/1)

Comment: i didn't get any error but what i am getting was not desired results....what was made to down my vote?...can i know

Comment: My query should return exactly what your example requires. If not, then please tell the differences.

Comment: sorry brother it is not producing the expected results.....actually i need the count of students for particular course name irrespective of course_id

Comment: My query returns the results your question. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592e4/1. Please correct your question if it is wrong.